# Weierstrass M-test counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let's consider the uniform convergence of the integral $ \displaystyle \int\limits_0^\infty f(x,y)dx $ on the some segment $[c,d]$. We know the Weierstrass M-test as the sufficient condition of uniform convergence. Is there any simple countexplamle proving that M-test is not neccesary?

I know the example $ \displaystyle\int\limits_1^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{y^2}(x-\frac{1}{y})^2}dx $. Is there any simpler examples?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Again "uniform convergence of integral"? Have I missed something or there is no such thing?

Comment: @Joanpemo do you want to say that there is no such thing as uniform convergence of the integral depending on a parameter?

Comment: @St Ah, the parameter. I missed that, and thus the integral can be made into a function of that parameter. Thank you. It is just that some short time ago there was an odd question about uniform convergece of a standard improper integral without parameters.

Comment: This is a valid question. Uniform convergence of an improper integral adresses if $\int_0^cf(x,y) dx$ is uniformly convergent as $c \to \infty$ for all values of the parameter $y$ in some set.